Is this SSD salvageble after power loss
While renovating my kitchen, a contractor pulled the breaker to safely work on electrics. However my PC was running at that point.
After the power was turned back on, one of my SSDs (a Samsung 870 EVO 2TB) was not working anymore.
The drive is about 3 years old and was working normally prior to the power loss. It looks like might be something with the controller. As trying to access the drive in any way leads to about a 10 minute freeze. I don't care about the data on the drive as it was just a data drive, but if possible I would like to still use it. Are there still things I can try, or is the drive dead?
I've checked the following things, mostly on Windows:

Device manager find the drive as normal;

Task manager shows drive, however it's always 100% active with 0mb/s read and 0mb/s write. An occasional drop in activity to about 90% with an occasional read. Average response is usually 0 ms, but every now and then jumps to about 2 seconds;

Windows Explorer shows drive with drive letter (D:), but no size indication or label. Trying to access freezes Windows Explorer;

Disk management shows drive as RAW (healthy). Disk management took about 10 minutes to load any information;

Deleting the partition on the drive results in an I/O error;
Formatting drive also results in an I/O error;


CHKDSK shows drive as NTFS, lists errors but is unable to fix errors. Takes about 10 minutes to get to that point;

CrystalDiskInfo fails to find drive after loading for a long time. Other drives are found as normal;

Samsung Magician fails to find drive after loading for a long time. Other drives are found as normal;

DISKPART clean fails with an I/O issue;

Changing power settings made no difference;

Event Viewer has a lot of warnings in the 'System' tab. Mostly three different ones:

{Delayed Write Failed} Windows was unable to save all the data for the file . The data has been lost. This error may be caused by a failure of your computer hardware or network connection. Please try to save this file elsewhere.

The IO operation at logical block address 0x8010 for Disk 0 (PDO name: \Device\0000003d) was retried.

The system failed to flush data to the transaction log. Corruption may occur in VolumeId: D:, DeviceName: \Device\HarddiskVolume6.
 Failure status: The I/O device reported an I/O error.

 Device GUID: {63a3251b-ae10-a94f-02d2-ee7dd5e910dd}
 Device manufacturer: 
 Device model: Samsung SSD 870 EVO 2TB
 Device revision: SVT01B6Q
 Device serial number: S621NF0R406962Y
 Bus type: SATA

 Adapter serial number:




Plugging the drive in a different PC, with a different SATA cable. Same issues there;



Go to a repair shop.

Sounds like the drive is in read only mode. The data referenced by the event manager is obviously gone. There are some non-consumer tools that a repair shop might have but everything you describe suggests the chances of you finding a consumer tool to restore the data yourself is very low.

Coincidence doesn't equal correlation. AFAIK, abrupt power loss can't fry solid state storage - over-voltage/current can, but power loss can't unless the firmware for the drive was being updated when power was lost (routers use similar NVRAM storage - think how many times we unplug routers). File systems on a drive will definitely have an issue if power is lost while writes were occurring, as will the OS (some filesystems are unrepairable after doing so, such as ZFS with a single drive pool). IIRC EVOs have a 5yr warranty - have you tried a known-good SATA cable and known-good SATA port?

@r2d3 Thanks, fixed the typo.

@Ramhound I'll look into a place nearby that might be able to help. I'm not looking to recover the data though. Just make the drive usable again. Games I can always redownload

@Thomas There's no reason to take the SSD to a local place - the drive has a five year warranty, so simply submit it for an RMA on Samsung's website

Boot into a Linux system (any live USB), then use hdparm to run ATA Enhanced Secure Erase. There's a very small chance that it will help (by asking the drive to reset all its contents and treat all flash as not-yet-written), though I'm only suggesting this because it happened to help with two SSDs from a completely different manufacturer, so no guarantee whatsoever.
